# Why am I getting a blank page in my servlet program

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using netbeans 8.2 and using Apache Tomcat server. Whenever I run the program I get to the registration page. But when I submit the information I am supposed to get an output. But I always get a blank page.I am using the database present in JAVA. Please Help I have to submit my java project;_;. I still need to create a login page.
Thanks in Advance.

**Jsp Program**

```
<%-- 
Document   : registeration
Created on : Mar 12, 2019, 10:24:50 AM
Author     : Pranav Sharma
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <form action="Registeration" method="POST">
        User Name:<input type="text" name="user" required="required"><br>
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" 
        required="required"><br>
        Age : <input type="text" name="age" required="required" /><br>
        Gender : <select name="gender">
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
            <option>Transgender</option>
        </select><br>
        Event : <select name="event" multiple="multiple">
            <option>Mr.Tanwar Body Building</option>
            <option>Fashion Show</option>
            <option>Dance</option>
            <option>Singing</option>
            <option>Coding</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" />
        <input type="reset" value="RESET" />

    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

**Servlet Program**

```
     package jdbc;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.sql.Connection;
     import java.sql.DriverManager;
     import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
     import java.sql.SQLException;
     import java.util.logging.Level;
     import java.util.logging.Logger;
     import javax.servlet.ServletException;
     import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
     @WebServlet(name="Registeration", urlPatterns={"/Registeration"})

     public class Registeration extends HttpServlet 
     {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Registeration(){
    super();
}

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    try {
        String name = request.getParameter("user");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String event = request.getParameter("event");
        String sql = "insert into 
        registeration(name,password,age,gender,event) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/RegForm","pranav","sharma");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,password);
        ps.setString(3,age);
        ps.setString(4,gender);
        ps.setString(5,event);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("You have successfully registered!");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**Web-xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registeration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jdbc.Registeration</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registeration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: did your data gets inserted in your table ?

Comment: @Swati no the table is still empty.

Comment: did you get any exceptions ?

Comment: @Ros5292 I got exceptions but I somehow solved them(thanks to stack overflow). But all I get now is blank screen.;_;

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi its in my course in college. ;_;

Comment: Did you add jar files in your lib folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a java-servlet project which uses sql server as a database. Underline project takes input from the ui and persist into database.

After inserting data into database, it will show up is records inserted successfully or not.

Change the DBConnectionUtils according to your database

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "root";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

This is the link for the project on github https://github.com/rosmahajan/java-servlet

Otherwise please post more information like any exception or error you are getting to investigate what is wrong with your code.

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: Thanks. I will try your code and let you know if I get anywhere.Also I just wanted to ask if i was doing anything wrong in my code. I am a newbie to servlet and jsp. Just want to know if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I am not getting any errors or exceptions. Just a blank page whenever I fill the form and submit it.

Comment: but your data is not inserted into database right ?